# How to make radius input automatically appear (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that takes the input, radius given by the user.

**For example:**

If radius is 2.
I want the program to output:

`"The volume of this sphere with radius 2 is: 33.51"`

I have used the variable `a` to store the radius that the user inputs.
So far, I have printed
`print("The volume of this sphere with radius a is:",  )`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do research before asking any question. 
Refer [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use f-string for this:

```
print(f'The volume of this sphere with radius a is:{4*math.pi*a**3/3}')
```